# react-metrics - Creating the vendor (new GoogleAnalytics)

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, vendor

I'm probably really stupid for not being able to figure this out.
But I'm having a hard time finding what or where to get the GoogleAnalytics class from.

It's not described in the repository, does anyone know where to find this?

```
const WrappedApplication = metrics({
vendors: [{
    name: "Google Analytics",
    api: new GoogleAnalytics({
        trackingId: ...
    })
}],
pageDefaults: ...
})(Application);
```

Preferably as a module since I'm working with React, like the library in question would have you believe.

p.s. I also used the create-react-app tool to set up the project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by the GoogleAnalytics class ? The snippet that tracks your site?

Comment: It's used in this config `const WrappedApplication = metrics({
    vendors: [{
        name: "Google Analytics",
        api: new GoogleAnalytics({
            trackingId: ...
        })
    }],
    pageDefaults: ...
})(Application);`

Comment: Where in that code? Do you mean the tracking id?

Comment: the api property is filled with an instance of a class, It's the class that I'm unable to locate.